# Fetch data from localhost cassandra db in react clientside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cassandra, connection

I am looking to get data from a localhost cassandra database in my react web application. I have looked around and I have not found a solution to this, and the npm driver package is designed to be run in the back end, not the front end.

How can I get data from the cassandra database into my react web application?

Thanks

Comment: you need to have some middleware for that...

Answer (score 0):

We have fully-working [sample React apps here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/sample-apps.html) that are built on JAMStack + Netlify on [Astra](https://dtsx.io/3oUbsNq) (Cassandra-as-a-service) with the complete code for free. Cheers!